# Call Python script from bash with merely the script name?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, terminal

I have written a couple of useful python scripts that I frequently call manually from bash with `/path/dir python script_name.py`.
However, it would be much more practical, if I could run my scripts by simply providing the script name to the terminal (without path, "python" and file extension): `script_name`

A couple more professional python applications offer this. For instance, Adrian Sampson's beets music management system, can be run by simply typing `beet` into a terminal.

How can I achieve something similar for my scripts?